# Node-Red dashboard template UI - AngularJS Bootstrap Carousel with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, node-red

I've been scratching my head to make a Bootstrap Carousel with AngularJS inside a Node-Red Dashboard template node. I have even found several tips here, but the presented solutions are not working for me... here is the complete code inside Node-Red dashboard template: (any help is much appretiatted!)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Spotify UI</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab md-on-select="send({getFeatured: true})" ng-click="send({getFeatured: true})">
            <md-tab-label><md-icon ng-md-icon icon="stars" style="fill: LIGHTGREEN"></md-icon></md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
            <md-content>  

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="item in featured track by $index">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{item.images[0].url}}" alt="missing">
      <p>{{$index}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

            </md-content>
      </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</md-content>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
(function(scope) {
  scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
    if (msg.payload.playlists.items) {
      scope.featured = msg.payload.playlists.items;
    };
  });
})(scope);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update 01.10.2018 - I finally managed to make it work after changing the class from `class="item"`to `class="carousel-item"`.

Comment: Hard to guess, without some clues on what is "not working"... But it is likely to have problems loading the external scripts due to timing issues -- try moving the script loading lines to another `ui_template` node set to "Add to site `<head>` section"

Comment: Hi, I have just created another `ui_template` as you suggested with the external scripts and it did not work either - the pictures are displayed on top of each other instead of horizontaly, how it is meant to be. Any further ideas please? By the way, the images are correctly displayed when I try the example from here [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/) without `ng-repeat` ... Thanks in advance!